# OPOS Configuration.xml DevicePath Property

Tags: c#, c++, opos

We use a windows iot version to do a cash drawer Service Object of OPOS.
We open the cash drawer using GPIO pin,so we communication with system
using Physical Memory address to do a open 
We don't know how to set a Hardware Device Path of Configuration file of POS.NET
environment.
Someone could help us to deal with the Hardware Device Path problem?

```
<Device HardwarePath="0xFED0C1D8" Enabled="yes" PnP="no">
  <LogicalName Name="WASPCD" />
</Device>
```

The HardwarePath="0xFED0C1D8" is our GPIO address ,is that right?

Comment: Configuration xml file is like

Comment: Are you writing the Service Object, or are you trying to configure a Service Object to work with your application?

Comment: yes,i wrote a service object,and the service object write a value to physical memory addres to control GPIO 's high / low , but OPOS seems like need to setup a configuration.xml to identify my hardwarepath,the value could be COM1,COM2,..but i don't know how to represent a physical memory address

Comment: i need config it,my service object write a value to physical memory addres to control GPIO 's high / low , but OPOS seems like need to setup a configuration.xml to identify my hardwarepath,the value could be COM1,COM2,..but i don't know how to represent a physical memory address

Comment: Since this is your Service Object, you can define however you want the configuration file to look in order to properly make your device work.  OPOS doesn't specify how you have to configure your own Service Object; it's not like they specify how you have to configure a Common Control.  If 0xDEADBEEF notation works for you, then that's just fine.  What's important to you is that you document configuring the Service Object for your clients.

Answer (score 0):

If the cash drawer service object you are using is made by OPOS instead of POS for.NET, you do not need to write the configuration.xml of POS for.NET.

1. Please make sure that Common Control Objects are installed.
2. Follow the procedure below to open the cash drawer device in the application.

   2-1.Acquire the device collection by calling the GetDevices method with CashDrawer as the type parameter and Opos or OposAndCompatibilityLevel1 as the compatibility parameter.

   2-2. Search the device information with the device name key or logical device name of the device being used defined in the OPOS registry from the acquired device collection, and perform CreateInstance based on it.

   2-3. Call Open method using created object.